# Adding Title to URL Meteor Iron Router

Tags: url, meteor, iron-router

Currently I have

```
http://www.example.com/videos/videoId
```

In my iron router,

```
Router.route('/videos/:_id', { name: 'videoShowtemplate' }
```

I want to make my site more seo friendly so I was thinking of adding
the video title to the URL.

```
http://www.example.com/videos/videoId/videoTitle
```

can you tell me how i can do this? thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go through the docs: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md

Keep the same route and just add /:slug to your params.

Do all your validations on `_id`

```
Router.route('/videos/:_id/:slug', { 
    template: 'videoShowtemplate' 
}
```

use the following code to redirect to the site

in html

```
<a href="/videos/{{_id}}/{{title}}">click here</a>
```

or in js

```
Router.go('videoShowtemplate', {_id: id,slug: title});
```

Comment: so slug doesn't really do anything? like /videos/videoId/title1 and /videos/videoId/title2 would point to the same video as long as the ID is the same?

Comment: Yes, If you want slug to do something then while searching for video add slug to the query `Videos.findOne({_id:id,title:slug});` this will return video only both are matched